# Loadrunner 12 Truclient Copy & Paste

Tags: loadrunner, truclient

I'm using Loadrunner 12 on recording a test script in a application, using Ajax Truclient Protocol.
The workflow contains a step to copy a large number of text fields from a excel sheet/or a text file, but the problem I'm facing is when the truclient execut this step it will paste a character at a time. eventually the step gets a time out & the test script is getting failed from there.
Hope if some one can help me out on this, to do the bulk txt copy paste step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the step that writes the text > Under `Typing Speed` change the value from `360` to `0`. This will boost up the typing execution when pasting the data (TruClient doesn't really paste the text - it actually types it).

Answer (score 0):

Please synchronize the steps. This will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the Help Naveen, I tried synchronizing the step & that solved the issue of step getting timed out. But then came another problem, the real workflow have the step to copy & paste the data from the excel but the truclient script is pasting a 1 character at a time. That makes my script to take much longer time to run than the real workflow. what I really need is to get all text to be pasted in the text field without typing one by one.

Comment: Nadeera, Think how the user behaves in real time, users enter one by one character while entering data. If you want to copy and paste whole string, you can do parameterization. This will solve your issue.

Comment: the data filed is parameterized but still the characters are pasting one at a time. I was able to find a some sort of a solution, but not the exactly what I need.

Comment: What I did was set the type delay to 1 mili second & that makes the character pasting very fast. Making the script step execution very small, even though still the characters pasting one at a time.
Thanks for looking in to this Naveen :)